# YAML unresolved external symbol (yaml-cpp)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, yaml, yaml-cpp

I have a YAML file consisting of:

```
abc: 123
```

And I'm using the following code to load it:

```
YAML::Node base = YAML::Load("test.yaml");
std::cout << base["abc"].as<int>() << std::endl;
```

MSVC fails to link (caused by the second line), stating:

```
unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > YAML::detail::node_data::empty_scalar"
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or if I just set it up wrong. It links and parses files fine, just doesn't let me use `YAML::Node::operator[]` without giving me an error.

Comment: That's not a compilation error.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/q/36403287/212870?

Answer (score 0):

You have to link with the `yaml-cpp` library.

Comment: I did link the library. Like I said, it will parse files file (which I will assume wouldn't work if I hadn't linked the library), I'm just having trouble accessing the data in the files after parsing them.

Comment: @Thoom Perhaps you should show the code which does work.

Comment: @AlanStokes If I remove the second line it works. I can also catch `YAML::ParserException`s being thrown to obtain error messages from an invalid YAML file. It's only when I access data from a file I've loaded (via `operator[]`) does my code no longer work. It's possible other functions are effected to, but I don't know much about the library.